# Как открыть порт на время в iptables/nftables?

Tags: linux, iptables

Например, поднял я Nginx и хочу показать команде. По умолчанию у меня `iptables -P INPUT DROP`.

Я хочу открыть его, скажем, на 1 час. Как это сделать?

Пока только пришла идея написать скрипт, где делать sleep А потом просто удалять правило. Но, может быть, есть готовое решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль тайм, но правило останется болтаться до перезагрузки [via](https://serverfault.com/a/537403/183600)

```
iptables -I INTPUT -m time --utc --datestart 2013-09-09T15:00 --datestop 2013-09-09T15:30 -j ACCEPT
```

Но лучше удалять его по команде at [via](https://serverfault.com/a/273328/183600) [via](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm)

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
echo "iptables -D INPUT  -j ACCEPT" | at now + 1 hour
```